# Spring Cloud Stream Binder Kafka - Dead Letter Topic in Different Cluster

Tags: spring-cloud-stream, spring-cloud-stream-binder-kafka

Is there a plan to support configuring a dead letter topic in a different cluster?

According to the below SO answer, the feature is not currently possible.
[Spring cloud Kafka Stream - Dead Letter Topic in Different Cluster](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66022095/spring-cloud-kafka-stream-dead-letter-topic-in-different-cluster)

I search the github issues, and SO questions about the issue.

The following SO question is relevant.
[Spring cloud Kafka Stream - Dead Letter Topic in Different Cluster](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66022095/spring-cloud-kafka-stream-dead-letter-topic-in-different-cluster)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That answer is nearly 2 years old.

You can use a `ListenerContainerCustomizer` bean to configure a `DefaultErrorHandler` with a `DeadLetterPublishingRecoverer` which is configured with a `KafkaTemplate` to send the record to a different cluster.

Disable retries/DLT in the binder and configure the error handler with the desired retry characteristics.

Comment: Thank you for the quick response! I found that the below two reference sections are also helpful!
* [handling deserialization errors with dlq](https://docs.spring.io/spring-cloud-stream/docs/current/reference/html/spring-cloud-stream-binder-kafka.html#_handling_deserialization_errors_with_dlq)
* [Publishing Dead-letter Records](https://docs.spring.io/spring-kafka/docs/current/reference/html/#dead-letters)